# Not able to use controls from toolbox in visual studio while working with xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and wanted to try its Getting Started module, and hence started with Hello, Android - Introduction to Android Development with Xamarin.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

I got stuck where I have to use the Plain Text control from the toolbox onto the designer, I am not able to use that control.
I am able to use only 1 control on the designer and if I try any other control, it doesn't allow.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't allow"? What happens exactly?

Comment: It shows that not allowed icon on drop.